# Traduction de l'anglais « part of speech »

Tags: grammaire, traduction

Dans la grammaire anglaise on appelle les catégories fondamentales de mot que l'on trouve dans un langage des « [part of speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part_of_speech) ». En anglais il y a traditionnellement huit de ces catégories :

- nom, verbe, adjectif, adverbe,  pronom, conjonction, préposition, interjection.

Trois autres catégories ne sont pas considérées comme de véritables catégories et sont seulement citées avec les huit catégories « principales » [dans certains cas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part_of_speech) : article,  (anglais) « numeral », (anglais) « determiner ».

En français on trouve le terme « catégorie grammaticale », mais il est évident qu'il décrit une plus grande catégorie ; voir par exemple le terme « catégorie grammaticale » dans les entrées « [syntagme](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/syntagme) », « [pluriel](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pluriel) » et [« actif »](http://stella.atilf.fr/Dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/visusel.exe?35;s=2222704695;r=2;nat=;sol=0;).

On trouve aussi le terme « partie du discours » qui, dans [reverso](https://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/part%20of%20speech/forced), est utilisé comme traduction de « part of speech » mais aussi de « catégorie grammaticale ».

Existe-t-il un terme en français *qui soit le plus courant* et qui n'englobe que les huits catégories initiales de la grammaire anglaise et la catégorie des articles, cela compte tenue qu'en français l'article est une catégorie à part entière ? Quels sont ses synonymes s'il en existe ?

Comment: Pourquoi le terme donné par la colonne de traduction de Wikipedia ne conviendrait-il pas ?

Comment: @Gilles Je ne connais pas cette colonne.

Comment: @subsexdexter Je vous remercie de ce renseignement, il m'a mené à une nouvelle possibilité, celle de faire faire la traduction complète d'une page entière.

Comment: Il n'y a pas de quoi ! Merci.

Comment: @LPH c'est aussi très pratique pour traduire des "concepts", qui sont trop vagues pour avoir une entrée dans le dictionnaire.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat An exemple ou deux  de ces serait le bienvenu.

Comment: I wanted to add example but they're not that easy to find. I can cite the [triad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triad_(music)), that didn't have an entry in wordreference. There isn't really a term in french other that the lengthy one given as a title: "accord de trois note". There are also pages that don't exist in English, like Fonction nulle and Vecteur nul, that work as nouns because of our vocabulary. There isn't an unambiguous adjective in english to say something equals 0. (A "null vector" is something else)

Comment: @TeleportingGoat There is the term "zero function" for "fonction nulle" and it is the standard term I believe; it's true that "zero" is not an adjective but as a modifier it takes on the role of one and thereby there is little difference. (zero vector, also).

Comment: you're right, I think found tat those pages didn't exist when I tried to find how to say "nul" in English. Dictionaries gave nothing, so I thought "well I just have to find the page for "Vecteur Nul" and go to the english page!" That has worked for other things, but didn't for "nul" ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un très bonne traduction de *part of speech* est la **nature** - on parle de *nature d'un mot*. On peut aussi employer les termes suivants:

- Catégorie lexicale
- Catégorie grammaticale
- Classe grammaticale
- Partie de discours (moins courant)

Les classifications possibles sont:

- nom
- verbe
- adjectif
- adverbe
- déterminant
- pronom
- mot de liaison

Exemples d'usage:

> - John parle bien français mais il n'a jamais appris à identifier la nature des mots.
> - Dans la phrase *Le chat miaule et le chien aboie*, les mots *chien* et *chat* appartiennent à la même classe grammaticale.

Comment: Je crois que « nature » peut être très utile, mais il n'est pas assez spécifique et ne fournit pas le nom d'une classe mais le nom de ce qui constitue l'essence d'un mot ; la classe prend sous son aile un élément qui se répète dans la **nature** de plusieurs choses : par exemple, les véhicules sont des objets servant au déplacement ; cependant le fait d'avoir deux roues et pas de moteur, ce qui est de la nature de la bicyclette, ne concerne que la bicyclette. Je pense plutôt à « catégorie lexicale ». Vous est-il possible d'identifier les catégories lexicales ? (champ suivant)

Comment: On trouve par exemple dans le TLFi l'appellation « particule » qui pourrait entrer dans cette classification ; il me semble qu'il n'y ait pas une correspondance claire et nette. Ne doit-on pas dire plutôt que « partie de discours », « partie du discours » ?

Comment: Pourquoi éviter le mot « conjonction » ?